# Find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(z+2)(1+z^2)}$ in the domains (1), $D:1<|z|<4$, (ii) $D:4<|z|<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this exercise and it seemed a bit weird to me:

> Find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{(z+2)(1+z^2)}$ in the domains (1), $D:1<|z|<4$, (ii) $D:4<|z|<\infty$

I have been trying to find this Laurent series, but somehow the domains $D$ just don't seem to work. When I use partial fractions I get:

$\dfrac{1}{(z+2)(z+i)(z-i)}=\dfrac{1}{5} \dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{1}{1+%
\dfrac{2}{z}}-\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{10}+\dfrac{1}{5}i}{1-\dfrac{i}{z}}-%
\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{10}-\dfrac{1}{5}i}{1+\dfrac{i}{z}}$ which shows that the "outer" domain for each series would be at first sight:
$|z|>2$, $|z|>1$ and $|z|>1$ respectively, to get a series for $|z|>2$. For the inner  $1<|z|<2$ I can use a normal geometric series for the first term of the right side. For $0<|z|<1$ I can use a normal geometric series for all the terms.

But I don't see where would I be able to get the $4$.

Can I get it somehow?

Comment: @Chee Han I'm using geometric series in each case...

Comment: Maybe the answer is: (1) does not exist, (2) the "outer" domain expansion?

Comment: You're right, (2) is clearly true.

And for (1), it seems to be the case. Thanks.